# Creating React app stuck and not creating src and public folder

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18yybdLjkH3BKhrNZETeVmzQiUvaDcRqR/view?usp=sharing

See the above link for image for reference.

I have tried to Create React App but it is stuck. It is not creating src and public folder. I tried another system its working fine.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SLIBwp3krv2AG9pnNPO79HtKPv9XIsNR/view?usp=sharing

see the above link for image reference.

Sometimes Stick here not creating app

Comment: stuck where? please explain in detail.

Comment: open the link and see that image i have shared

Comment: how long have you been waiting?

Comment: more than 1 hour